# nginx: Configuring multiple vhost without a subdomain

Tags: linux, nginx

I have an nginx server. I have a public IP address but I don't have any subdomains. I would like to split my dev and test servers. So can I set up these servers ie

`http://55.22.11.127/dev` and `http://55.22.11.127/test`

I've tried this in config:

```
server_name 55.22.11.127/dev;
```

No luck...

So do I have to set up a domain or can I set up this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup one common server name with multiple location directives - the config should look something like this:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/html;

    server_name 55.22.11.127


    location /dev {
     #dev site config
    }


  location /test {
    # testing site config

    }

}
```